# SpringRest - no matching handler method found for servlet request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

No matching handler method found for servlet request: path '/test/add', method 'POST'....

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
 public class TestController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Accept=application/json",
        "Content-Type=application/json" })
public @ResponseBody String create(@RequestBody String body) {
    .....
}}
```

configuration :

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Change your dispatcher servlet mapping in your web.xml as below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because that your POST request is not a kind of "application/json"

watch out your request/